# How to update timeData as the time change using flutter GETx?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I want my app's time to change as time passed. I want to manage the state with **GETx**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this will work by

```
Timer.periodic(Duration(second:30), (timer) { updateTheState })
```